# Difference between a normal buffer and a space prefix buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

By a space prefix buffer, I mean buffers with names that start with a space. Not sure what's the official jargon for such buffers.

I thought the only difference of space prefix buffers were that undo was disabled on them, but there seem to be other differences which are causing the package `htmlize` to react differently to space prefix buffers.

```
(require 'htmlize)

;; function to write stuff on current buffer and call htmlize-region
(defun my-test-htmlize ()
  (insert "1234567")
  (emacs-lisp-mode)
  ;; (put-text-property 1 2 'font-lock-face "bold")
  (put-text-property 3 4 'font-lock-face 'bold)
  (with-current-buffer (htmlize-region (point-min)
                                       (point-max))
    (buffer-string)))

;; function that makes a (failed) attempt to make current buffer behave like a normal buffer
(defun my-make-buffer-normal ()
  (buffer-enable-undo))

;; like with-temp-buffer, except it uses a buffer that is not a space prefix buffer.
(defmacro my-with-temp-buffer-with-no-space-prefix (&rest body)
  (declare (indent 0) (debug t))
  (let ((temp-buffer (make-symbol "temp-buffer")))
    `(let ((,temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*tempwd2kemgv*")))
       (with-current-buffer ,temp-buffer
         (unwind-protect
             (progn ,@body)
           (and (buffer-name ,temp-buffer)
                (kill-buffer ,temp-buffer)))))))

;; In a normal buffer, bold face is htmlized.
(my-with-temp-buffer-with-no-space-prefix
  (my-test-htmlize))

;; In a space prefix buffer, bold face is not htmlized.
(with-temp-buffer
  (my-test-htmlize))

;; Bold face is still not htmlized.
(with-temp-buffer
  (my-make-buffer-normal)
  (my-test-htmlize))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leading spaces indicate ephemeral or uninteresting buffers.  These have no undo history, and many commands place these buffers less prominently, or even ignore them completely.  See [Emacs Lisp Reference, Buffer Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html#Buffer-Names):

> Buffers that are ephemeral and generally uninteresting to the user have names starting with a space, so that the list-buffers and buffer-menu commands don't mention them (but if such a buffer visits a file, it is mentioned). A name starting with space also initially disables recording undo information; see Undo.

There are no further differences on built-in commands, but any command is free to handle these buffers in a special way.  You probably need to consult the htmlize sources to determine the cause of the different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Found another difference of buffers with names starting with a space. Additional manual font lock will not work with such buffers.

```
(defmacro my-with-temp-buffer-with-name (buffername &rest body)
  (declare (indent 1) (debug t))
  (let ((temp-buffer (make-symbol "temp-buffer")))
    `(let ((,temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer ,buffername)))
       (with-current-buffer ,temp-buffer
         (unwind-protect
             (progn ,@body)
           (and (buffer-name ,temp-buffer)
                (kill-buffer ,temp-buffer)))))))

(my-with-temp-buffer-with-name "*temp*"
  (insert "1234567")
  (emacs-lisp-mode)
  (put-text-property 3 4 'font-lock-face 'bold)
  (print (next-single-property-change 1 'face)))
;; => 3

(my-with-temp-buffer-with-name " *temp*" ; with a space prefix
  (insert "1234567")
  (emacs-lisp-mode)
  (put-text-property 3 4 'font-lock-face 'bold)
  (print (next-single-property-change 1 'face)))
;; => nil
```

**Update:** The reason the additional font lock does not work is because font-lock-mode actively avoids working with such buffers (see definition of `font-lock-mode`) One way to make it work is to call `font-lock-default-function` directly.

```
(my-with-temp-buffer-with-name " *temp*" ; with a space prefix
  (insert "1234567")
  (emacs-lisp-mode)
  (put-text-property 3 4 'font-lock-face 'bold)
  (font-lock-default-function t) ; <==
  (print (next-single-property-change 1 'face)))
;; => 3
```